# How to know if a method is thread safe

Tags: java

Suppose I have a method that checks for a id in the db and if the id doesn't exit then inserts a value with that id. How do I know if this is thread safe and how do I ensure that its thread safe. Are there any general rules that I can use to ensure that it doesn't contain race conditions and is generally thread safe.

```
public TestEntity save(TestEntity entity) {
       if (entity.getId() == null) {
            entity.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
        Map<String, TestEntity > map = dbConnection.getMap(DB_NAME);
        map.put(entity.getId(), entity);
        return map.get(entity.getId());
}
```

Comment: Since you are using something other than primitives, you have to check on all the underlying calls

Comment: You could make a method thread safe with [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: Why don't you leave the ID to the database by using an auto_increment?

Comment: what's your ORM?

Comment: You can be totally sure that this one *isn't* thread-safe, by considering what happens if another thread runs it between each line of code.

Comment: @Robert, autoincrement is a another good way to go, but not all databases have that facility and some of those that do (especially MPP ones) can quickly exhaust the available ID's and/or have some performance impacts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a how long is a piece of string question...

A **method** will be thread safe if it uses the synchronized keyword in its declaration.

However, even if your setId and getId methods used synchronized keyword, your **process** of setting the id (if it has not been previously initialized) above is not. .. but even then there is an "it depends" aspect to the question. If it is **impossible** for two threads to ever get the same object with an uninitialised id then you are thread safe because you would never be attempting to concurrently modifying the id.

It is entirely possible, given the code in your question, that there could be two calls to the thread safe getid at the same time for the same object. One by one they get the return value (null) and immediately get pre-empted to let the other thread run. This means both will then run the thread safe setId method - again one by one.

You could declare the whole save method as synchronized, but if you do that the entire method will be single threaded which defeats the purpose of using threads in the first place. You tend to want to minimize the synchronized code to the bare minimum to maximize concurrency.

You could also put a synchronized block around the critical if statement and minimise the single threaded part of the processing, but then you would also need to be careful if there were other parts of the code that might also set the Id if it wasn't previously initialized.

Another possibility which has various pros and cons is to put the initialization of the Id into the get method and make that method synchronized, or simply assign the Id when the object is created in the constructor.

I hope this helps...

Edit...
The above talks about java language features. A few people mentioned facilities in the java class libraries (e.g. java.util.concurrent) which also provide support for concurrency. So that is a good add on, but there are also whole packages which address the concurrency and other related parallel programming paradigms (e.g. parallelism) in various ways.

To complete the list I would add tools such as [Akka](https://akka.io/) and [Cats-effect (concurrency)](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency) and more.

Not to mention the books and courses devoted to the subject.

I just reread your question and noted that you are asking about databases. Again the answer is it depends. Rdbms' usually let you do this type of operation with record locks usually in a transaction. Some (like teradata) use special clauses such as `locking row for write select * from some table where pi_cols = 'somevalues'` which locks the *rowhash* to you until you update it or certain other conditions. This is known as pessimistic locking.

Others (notebly nosql) have optimistic locking. This is when you read the record (like you are implying with getid) there is no opportunity to lock the record. Then you do a conditional update. The conditional update is sort of like this: `write the id as x provided that when you try to do so the Id is still null (or whatever the value was when you checked)`. These types of operations are usually down through an API.

You can also do optimistics locking in an RDBMs as follows:
`SQL
Update tbl 
Set x = 'some value',
     Last_update_timestamp = current_timestamp()
Where x = bull AND last_update_timestamp = 'same value as when I last checked'`

In this example the second part of the where clause is the critical bit which basically says "only update the record if no one else did **and** I trust that everyone else will update the last update to when they do". The "trust" bit can sometimes be replaced by triggers.

These types of database operations (if available) are guaranteed by the database engine to be "thread safe".

Which loops me back to the "how long is a piece of string" observation at the beginning of this answer...

Comment: So in essence, is there no way of writing thread safe code without making it  single threaded(synchronized)?

Comment: Sorry, but `synchronized` is not the only way to make a method thread-safe, nor is it universally the best. It could be that underlying methods are synchronized already, use other primitives such as reentrant read/write locks, have lock-free thread safety, or interact with a database that has per-thread connections and is externally consistent.

Comment: @user3310115 There are plenty of ways, including using building blocks that are already inherently thread-safe in proper ways.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov - Can you please elaborate? All the material I read only points to synchronised or removing mutations but this is not possible in the real world.

Comment: @user3310115 I can't really elaborate since a complete discussion thread-safe programming wouldn't fit in a comment or even an answer, but there are features in `java.util.concurrent` that allow constructing thread-safe programs using building blocks aside from simple mutual exclusion (e.g. a synchronized block). Certainly, throwing synchronization on a method is a cheap and fast way to move toward thread-safety but it's not the most efficient... but you can start by just thinking through all possible concurrent modifications that can occur and seeing if any are harmful.

Comment: Seriously folks, there are complete books on how to do (thread-safe) concurrent programming in Java.   The idea that you can condense that down to a StackOverflow Q&A ... let alone a comment or two ... is fanciful.

Comment: What Stephen said reminded me of the next challenge when you start trying to be thread safe - deadlocks. Which will then move on to message passing systems, futures, promises, deferrals and so on. Which is why there are whole books and indeed whole courses on concurrent programming... hence my openning comment "this is a how long is a piece of string question..." :-)

Comment: Synchronized does not mean something is thread safe.  It means no other thread can re-enter any other block that's synchronized at the same time.  A trivial way thread safety can be broken is if another non-synchronized function on another thread alters any variables it uses.

Comment: Agreed @Gabe_Sechan I tried to address that in my highlighting that even if the individual methods are synchronized, the process in the OP is in fact not due to the possibility of preempting during the if statement between the get and set calls.

Comment: Sad face :-( to whover down voted my answer - may I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

## Test-and-set is unsafe

> a method that checks for a id in the db and if the id doesn't exit then inserts a value with that id.

Any test-and-set pair of operations on a shared resource is inherently unsafe, vulnerable to a [race condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software). If the two operations are separate (not atomic), then they must be protected as a pair. While one thread completes the test but has not yet done the set, another thread could sneak in and do both the test and the set. The first thread now completes its set without knowing a duplicate action has occurred.

Providing that necessary protection is too broad a topic for an Answer on Stack Overflow, as others have said here.

## `UPSERT`

However, let me point out that an alternative approach to to **make the test-and-set atomic**.

- In the context of a database, that can be done using the [UPSERT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)#upsert) feature. Also known as a Merge operation. For example, in Postgres 9.5 and later we have the `INSERT INTO … ON CONFLICT` command. See [this explanation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) for details.
- In the context of a Boolean-style flag, a [semaphore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) makes the test-and-set atomic.

Comment: Semaphores don't make a test and set atomic, they typically rely on having an atomic test and set as their implementation.  Although if you lock all access to a variable with checks to a semaphore that is sufficient for atomicity (assuming the semaphore itself has no bugs).

Comment: @GabeSechan Your first sentence is exactly the point I was making. The context being discussed here the nature of the atomic test-and-set which is what separates a semaphore from a regular boolean. Using a semaphore as a locking mechanism is beside the point here and irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

In general, when we say "a method is thread-safe" when there is no race-condition to the internal and external data structure of the object it belongs to. In other words, the order of the method calls are strictly enforced.

For example, let's say you have a HashMap object and two threads, thread_a and thread_b.

thread_a calls put("a", "a") and thread_b calls put("a", "b").

The put method is not thread-safe (refer to its documentation) in the sense that while thread_a is executing its put, thread_b can also go in and execute its own put.

A put contains reading and writing part.

```
thread_a.read("a")
thread_b.read("a")
thread_b.write("a", "b")
thread_a.write("a", "a")
```

If above sequence happens, you can say ... a method is not thread-safe.

How to make a method thread-safe is by ensuring the state of the whole object cannot be perturbed while the thread-safe method is executing. An easier way is to put "synchronized" keyword in method declarations.

If you are worried about performance, use manual locking using synchronized blocks with a lock object. Further performance improvement can be achieved using a very well designed semaphores.